# Laravel 4 Eager Loading in Many to Many Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Trying to do a simple eager load with Laravel 4 using a many to many relationships. My Models look like.

```
class Facility extends Eloquent {

    public function photos(){
            return $this->belongsToMany('Photo');
    }
}

class Photo extends Eloquent {

    public function facilities(){
            return $this->belongsToMany('Facility');
    }
}
```

Tabes are set up according to Laravel standards. When I try to load using

```
$facilities = Facility::with('Photo')->get();
```

I end up with a Laravel error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::photo()
```

Any idea whats being done wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try:

```
$facilities = Facility::with('photos')->get();
```

Remember, the argument you are passing to `with()` is the method, not the model, so if you have another method in the model, say: `location()`, you'll call:

```
$facilities = Facility::with(['photos', 'location'])->get();
```

Comment: if photos have reference how do i eager load it ?

Comment: If the Photo model has a reference() relation, you could try: `$facilities = Facility::with('photos.reference')->get();`

Comment: @AladinBouzerd `"Remember, the argument you are passing to with() is the method, not the model"` <- This. Thank you Aladin!